# how to generate symbol Class<?> with javapoet

Tags: javapoet

i want to generate a field like this:

```
public static Map<String, Class<?>> ID_MAP = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
```

WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(Object.class) can give '?'
WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(Class.class)  can give 'Class'

Answer (score 13):

If you break down that type into its component parts you get:

- `?`
- `Class`
- `Class<?>`
- `String`
- `Map`
- `Map<String, Class<?>>`

You can then build up these component parts in the same way using JavaPoet's APIs:

- `TypeName wildcard = WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(Object.class);`
- `TypeName cls = ClassName.get(Class.class);`
- `TypeName clsWildcard = ParameterizedTypeName.create(cls, wildcard);`
- `TypeName string = ClassName.get(String.class);`
- `TypeName map = ClassName.get(Map.class);`
- `TypeName mapStringClass = ParameterizedTypeName.create(map, string, clsWildcard);`

Once you have that type, doing the same for `HashMap` should be easy (just replace `Map.class` with `HashMap.class`) and then building the field can be done like normal.

```
FieldSpec.builder(mapStringClass, "ID_MAP")
    .addModifiers(PUBLIC, STATIC)
    .initializer("new $T()", hashMapStringClass)
    .build();
```

Comment: sorry,i cant find ParameterizedTypeName.create(xx,xx) in ParameterizedTypeName.java

Comment: Use `ParameterizedTypeName.get()`

Answer (score 8):

Using [`ParameterizedTypeName.get()`](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/squareup/javapoet/ParameterizedTypeName.java#L110) worked for me -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    TypeName wildcard = WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(Object.class);

    TypeName classOfAny = ParameterizedTypeName.get(
            ClassName.get(Class.class), wildcard);

    TypeName string = ClassName.get(String.class);

    TypeName mapOfStringAndClassOfAny = ParameterizedTypeName.get(ClassName.get(Map.class), string, classOfAny);

    TypeName hashMapOfStringAndClassOfAny = ParameterizedTypeName.get(ClassName.get(HashMap.class), string, classOfAny);

    FieldSpec fieldSpec = FieldSpec.builder(mapOfStringAndClassOfAny, "ID_MAP")
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC)
            .initializer("new $T()", hashMapOfStringAndClassOfAny)
            .build();

    TypeSpec fieldImpl = TypeSpec.classBuilder("FieldImpl")
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
            .addField(fieldSpec)
            .build();

    JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("com", fieldImpl)
            .build();

    javaFile.writeTo(System.out);
}
```

---

Imports used by me -

```
import com.squareup.javapoet.*;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
```

---

This generates the output as -

> ```
> package com;
>
> import java.lang.Class;
> import java.lang.String;
> import java.util.HashMap;
> import java.util.Map;
>
> public final class FieldImpl {
>   public static Map<String, Class<?>> ID_MAP = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
> }
> ```